# Access generated values from app.js inside a script loaded via require()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express.js Node web app. Inside my app.js, I generate a string during app initialization:

```
// app.js
var mongourl = /* based on process.env.VCAP_SERVICES constant */;
```

Now, I have a script that I load into app.js via require():

```
// app.js
var db = require('./db');
```

This script needs to use the `mongourl` variable defined in my app.js. What would be a good approach to perform this. I have found that I can just set the string as a `process.env` value, e.g.

```
// app.js
process.env.mongourl = /* creating the string */;
```

which then can be accessed in db.js via `process.evn.mongourl` but I'm not sure if this is a good pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
// in db.js you could require an app config.js file
var config = require('config');
// then access via config.db.url

// or you can pass stuff to modules
var db = require('./db')(mongourl);

// or in app.js use app.set()
app.set('mongourl', mongourl);
// then wherever you need it: app.get('mongourl')
```

Comment: W.r.t option #2 above, note that the require() is expected to return a function that takes the Mongo URL as an argument. So the DB module would need something like:

var db_url;

module.exports = function(url) { db_url = url; ..... };

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure if this is a good pattern

It isn't, you just pollute the global object that doesn't belong to you. Consider using a namespace, at least.

Comment: As in `process.env.FOO.mongourl`?

Answer (score 0):

A more idiomatic approach would be to create a constructor function for the db connection which takes the string.

It doesn't have to be an actual constructor you could just add

```
var dburl;
exports.init = function(param) {
     dburl = param:
}
```

Environmental variables aren't meant for that really as they are global and can be seen (and collide with)  other modules.  Setting it explicitly means it's local and you have much more explicit control of how it's defined if you need it async.